# Trainable custom Keras layer using a Tensorflow wrapper for Numpy functions

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to create a custom Keras layer which is a general-purpose wrapper for functions which operate on numpy arrays and return numpy arrays. I am using a Tensorflow 2.0 back end for Keras.

I think this could be really useful for anyone who has some outside code they want to implement as a trainable Keras layer.

My strategy was to use `tf.numpy_fun` together with the `@tf.custom_gradient` decorator to define a differentiable Tensorflow operator which wraps a Numpy function. In principle, if there is a way to call the function and also a custom function to compute gradients, it should be trainable via backpropagation.

Here I show an example implementing the nonlinear transformation: **y=B*exp(-A*x)** I verified that the tensorflow function was compatible Tensorflow's automatic differentiation using `tf.GradientTape()`

But when I try to implement the function in a custom Keras layer I get an error that I don't fully understand. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def myNumpyFun(B,A,x):
    z = np.exp( - A.dot( x ) )
    y = B.dot( z )
    return (y,z)

def myNumpyFunGrad(B,A,x,z,dC_dyT):

    tmp = dC_dyT
    tmp = B.transpose().dot( tmp )
    tmp = z*tmp
    tmp = A.transpose().dot( tmp )
    tmp = -tmp
    dC_dxT = tmp

    tmp = dC_dyT
    tmp = B.transpose().dot( tmp )
    tmp = z*tmp
    XT = np.kron(np.eye(A.shape[0]),x)
    tmp = XT.dot(tmp)
    tmp = -tmp
    dC_daT = tmp
    dC_dAT = dC_daT.reshape(A.shape)

    tmp = dC_dyT
    ZT = np.kron(np.eye(B.shape[0]),z)
    tmp = ZT.dot(tmp)
    dC_dbT = tmp
    dC_dBT = dC_dbT.reshape(B.shape)

    return (dC_dBT, dC_dAT, dC_dxT)


@tf.custom_gradient
def myTensorflowFun(B,A,x):
    (y,z) = tf.numpy_function(myNumpyFun, [B,A,x], tf.float32)
    def grad(dC_dyT):
        return tf.numpy_function(myNumpyFunGrad, [B,A,x,z,dC_dyT], tf.float32)
    return y, grad

class MyKerasLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self,shapeA,shapeB, **kwargs):
        self.shapeA = shapeA
        self.shapeB = shapeB
        super(MyKerasLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.A = self.add_weight(name='A',
                                 shape=self.shapeA,
                                 initializer='uniform',
                                 trainable=True)
        self.B = self.add_weight(name='B',
                                 shape=self.shapeB,
                                 initializer='uniform',
                                 trainable=True)
        super(MyKerasLayer, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, x):
        def fun(w):
            return myTensorflowFun(self.B,self.A,w)
        return tf.map_fn(fun, x, dtype=tf.float32)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return self.call(tf.ones(input_shape)).shape


inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=((2,1)),dtype=float)
outputs = MyKerasLayer([3,2],[4,3])(inputs)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=opt)

N=10000
x_train = np.random.rand(N,2,1).astype(float)
x_test = np.random.rand(N,2,1).astype(float)

A = np.arange(6).astype(float).reshape([3,2])
B = np.arange(12).astype(float).reshape([4,3])

y_train = np.zeros([N,4,1],dtype=float)
y_test = np.zeros([N,4,1],dtype=float)
for iSamp in np.arange(N):
    y_train[iSamp] = B.dot( np.exp(- A.dot( x_train[iSamp] ) ) )
    y_test[iSamp] = B.dot( np.exp(- A.dot( x_test[iSamp]   ) ) )


model.fit(  x_train,
            y_train,
            batch_size=32,
            epochs=5,
            verbose=1,
            validation_data=(x_test,y_test))


score = model.evaluate( x_test,
                        y_test,
                        verbose=0)

print('Test Loss: ', score)

weights = model.get_weights()

print('Trained Weights: ', weights)
```

When I run this, I get an error at the first `tf.numpy_fun` call inside`MyTensorflowFun`. Here is the error message:

**OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed in Graph execution. Use Eager execution or decorate this function with @tf.function.**

I am confused because I thought that Tensorflow has eager execution enabled by default. If I run `tf.executing_eagerly()` it returns `True`, but if I run it right before the error it returns `False`. Does this mean that Keras is executing in graph mode? How can I fix this?

Also interested if anyone has other general suggestions for accomplishing the goal of trainable numpy functions in a custom Keras layer.

Comment: I was able to get this working by passing ```dynamic=True``` on the call to ```MyKerasLayer```. According to Tensorflow docs, this forces eager execution. However, this makes it run much slower. Is there a way to modify this so it is compatible with graph execution? Does anyone know about compatibility of ```tensorflow.numpy_function``` and graph mode? Seems like this should be possible since @custom_gradient allows for auto differentiation